# contextMenu click handler is executing the command for the wrong menu item

Tags: node.js, menu, electron

In my electron app, I have code that reads a JSON file and inserts menu items:

```
var settingsdata = fs.readFileSync('./settings.json');
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(settingsdata);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonContent.length; i++) {
    var obj = null;
    obj = jsonContent[i];
    console.log(obj.label);
    console.log(obj.parameters);
    contextMenu.insert(0,new MenuItem({
        label: obj.label,
        click: function() {
            child_process.execFileSync(vExecutablePath, obj.parameters)
        },
        position: 'before'
    }))
}
```

The problem is with the click handler of the inserted menu items. It executes command with only last item that was inserted, but not individually, even if `console.log(obj.parameters)` shows the correct different parameters for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `var` with `let` in the `for` loop.

`var` is scoped to the function, so by the time the `click` handler is executed, `i` will be set to `jsonContent.length`.

When using `let` in a `for` loop, you'll get a new variable each iteration, which can be used in a closure (i.e. in the `click` handler in your case).